# Unable to 'brew link' imagemagick

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, homebrew, rmagick

I'm trying to install Imagemagick via brew, and I get this message upon installation:

```
    Warning: imagemagick-6.8.6-3 already installed, it's just not linked
```

When I attempt to link it via brew link, I get this:

```
    brew link imagemagick
    Warning: Could not link imagemagick. Unlinking...
    Linking /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.6-3... 
    Error: File exists - /usr/local/etc
```

Ideas?? I've tried:

```
    'brew link -f imagemagick'
```

without luck (I get the same error message as above). It was suggested here: [Brew linking with ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11878888/brew-linking-with-imagemagick)

According to brew update, I'm up to date. Brew doctor returns this:

```
    Warning: You have MacPorts or Fink installed:
    /Users/user_name/.rvm/bin/port, /opt/local/bin/port

    This can cause trouble. You don't have to uninstall them, but you may want to
    temporarily move them out of the way, e.g.

    sudo mv /opt/local ~/macports

   Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
   Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
   those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:

   imagemagick
```

Comment: probably a file in /usr/local/etc with bad permissions for a write. what does `ls -l /usr/local/etc` give you?

Comment: You should probably look into Brew doctor's warnings and fix them.

Comment: It gives me -rw-r--r-- 1.

Comment: and what user owns it? you or root?

Comment: amyway - you probably need to remove that file. if `rm <filename>` doesn't work you'll have to `sudo rm <filename>`

Comment: I removed the file, and brew link worked just fine! Thank you!!

Comment: nice - I'll add an answer for the record

Comment: Thanks froderik. Much appreciated, it was driving me crazy.

Comment: Heads up for anyone else. I had a file in the etc dir but not imagemagick. I deleted the whole directory and it recreated it and installed successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the imagemagick file in `/usr/local/etc` so that brew can write a new one there.

The old file was placed there by something else than brew. Possibly another package manager.

UPDATE 2015.03.07: as Chords indicated in a comment above it may be necessary to remove the folder entirely. (Although setting the correct permissions and groups may be an equivalent measure.)