# Change permissions access denied brew link imagemagick

Tags: macos, imagemagick, homebrew, chmod

Imagemagick was improperly installed on my computer.  I have homebrew and when trying to link I encountered the same problems listed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700143/unable-to-brew-link-imagemagick)

```
Caseys-MacBook-Pro:~ CaseyJayne$ brew link imagemagick
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.8-13... 
Error: Could not symlink etc/ImageMagick-7/colors.xml
Target /usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-7/colors.xml already exists. You may want to remove it: rm '/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-7/colors.xml'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files: brew link --overwrite imagemagick

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run imagemagick
```

I tried force overwrite and it did not work.

```
Caseys-MacBook-Pro:~ CaseyJayne$ brew link --overwrite imagemagick
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.8-13... 
Error: Could not symlink etc/ImageMagick-7/colors.xml
/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-7 is not writable.
Caseys-MacBook-Pro:~ CaseyJayne$ brew link -f imagemagick
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.8-13... 
Error: Could not symlink etc/ImageMagick-7/colors.xml
Target /usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-7/colors.xml
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-7/colors.xml'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite imagemagick
```

I tried removing and moving the files

```
Caseys-MacBook-Pro:~ CaseyJayne$ rm '/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-7/colors.xml'
override rw-r--r--  root/wheel for /usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-7/colors.xml? yes
rm: /usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-7/colors.xml: Permission denied
Caseys-MacBook-Pro:~ CaseyJayne$ mv '/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-7/colors.xml' ~/Desktop/
mv: rename /usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-7/colors.xml to /Users/CaseyJayne/Desktop/colors.xml: Permission denied
```

I tried changing permissions to 755 for the entire etc file, changing the directories to 755 and folders to 644, and deleting the entire file with rmdir (all listed in the linked posts' comments).  I did the entire process again with the same output.  I ran brew doctor and followed instructions on everything that had to do with imagemagick.

Currently, the dry run gives this output:

```
Caseys-MacBook-Pro:~ CaseyJayne$ brew link --overwrite --dry-run imagemagick
Would remove:
```

1020 files in the /usr/local/etc/ /usr/local/bin/ /usr/local/share/ directories and sub directories
examples:

```
/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-7/colors.xml
/usr/local/bin/Magick++-config 
/usr/local/share/ImageMagick-7/locale.xml
```

What is my best options for changing the permissions or removing the files? 
Idea that makes me nervous: Manually show the hidden gui files, move them to the trash, run the brew link imagemagick, and then restore them from the trash into some other folder?

Also- no option has worked to uninstall imagemagick (sudo or yum at the beggining)

I am using a Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.6
Imagemagick 7.0.8-13
Homebrew 1.8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image Magick had a ton of files installed in my hidden files.  My coworker (who's been coding for years, dual PhD in neuroscience and engineering) helped me go through and manually remove the ones that said "magick" in any form.

We did this one at a time, to make sure we wouldn't haphazardly delete something that was necessary.  I've been using my computer for months now without problems and would say that this is the safest and most seamless way to do so.  The ^above solution didn't uninstall all the the things imagemagick put into my computer, but only removed one item.

Answer (score 1):

Your user have no rights on this file, but if you are admin of your computer you can remove it with `sudo`:

```
sudo rm '/usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-7/colors.xml'
```